# How to create button in my own View

Tags: android

I'm creating simple game to learn game development's basics on Android.

there is

```
class GameView extends View
```

I'm extend View (should I extend View? or ViewGroup? or Any Other? - There are basicly bitmaps in the game and may be some custom wigets)

There are sprites in this view and I want to create custom "STRIKE" button using ImageButton (should I use ImageButton wiget?)

How can I add wiget without using XML layout(!)

```
//for example simple Button
class GameView extends View
{
    private Button btn;


    public GameMainView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        btn = new Button(context);      
    }
}
```

How to display this Button in my game?

Answer (score 0):

You should extend `ViewGroup`: when you override `onDraw` you will get a `Canvas`. You'll have to manually set the position of the Button view but if you do that then call its draw method with the Canvas it should display fine.

EDIT: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html has the info you need. Look at the Compound Controls section.

Comment: I have read that using SurfaceView in the games is preferred. Is it right?
If I will use SurfaceView then I cannot use ViewGroup and it's childs

now my questions is this: How to add this wiget to the View/SurfaceView without using ViewGroup and Layouts?

Answer (score 0):

```
 Button btnabout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAbout);
    btnabout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View V) 
        {
            //do something
        }//end onClick          
    });//end button
```